# X- editable triggering from other element

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here is my question

I am working on x-editable I implemented it and it is working.

But now I need to activate the editable with the click of an external element

I got a solution like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.clickme").click(function(){
        $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');
    });
});
```

Jeditable - Activate edit of X by clicking on Y (reference for above code)

but it is only activating the portion the input box is not showing.

any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a good Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/348/

`$('#users').on('click', '.edit', function(){
    $('#users').find('.editable-open').editable('hide');
    $('#users').find('.btn-primary').hide();
    $('#users').find('.edit').show();
    $(this).hide().siblings('.btn-primary').show();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.editable').editable('show');
});`

Found in https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/80